# Hazelcast members in 2 different docker hosts

Tags: docker, hazelcast

The scenario is made by 2 VMs, each one with docker and hazelcast memebers running as containers.

Reading this guide https://hazelcast.com/blog/configuring-hazelcast-in-non-orchestrated-docker-environments/ I can get the Scenario 3 *Public IP address, port mapping, and TCP discovery method* working with one member per node.
But if I add a member to one of the nodes it takes the place of the other member in the cluster or logs connection problems. So I'm not able to make the cluster working with more than one member per node.

The configuration in both nodes is:

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - 10.132.0.2:5701
          - 10.128.0.3:5701
          - 10.128.0.3:5702
```

The Container in node `10.132.0.2` is run with:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/mnt --rm --name member1   -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Dhazelcast.local.
publicAddress=10.132.0.2 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.yml"   -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:4.0.1

########################################
# JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=10.132.0.2 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.yml
# CLASSPATH=/opt/hazelcast/*:/opt/hazelcast/lib/*
# starting now....
########################################
+ exec java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=10.132.0.2 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.yml com.hazelcast.core.server.HazelcastMemberStarter
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:23 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator
INFO: Loading configuration '/mnt/hazelcast.yml' from System property 'hazelcast.config'
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:23 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator
INFO: Using configuration file at /mnt/hazelcast.yml
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [10.128.0.3, 10.132.0.2]
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
WARNING: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Picked [172.17.0.2]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Using public address: [10.132.0.2]:5701
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Hazelcast 4.0.1 (20200409 - e086b9c) starting at [10.132.0.2]:5701
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:24 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Backpressure is disabled
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:25 AM com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Creating TcpIpJoiner
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:25 AM com.hazelcast.cp.CPSubsystem
WARNING: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] CP Subsystem is not enabled. CP data structures will operate in UNSAFE mode! Please note that UNSAFE mode will not provide strong consistency guarantees.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:26 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:26 AM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:26 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.132.0.2]:5701 is STARTING
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:26 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:26 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:26 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5703, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:26 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5702. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.132.0.2:5702. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.132.0.2]:5702 is added to the blacklist.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.132.0.2:5703. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.128.0.3]:5702 is added to the blacklist.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.128.0.3]:5701 is added to the blacklist.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.132.0.2]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
Sep 29, 2020 6:35:37 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
        Member [10.132.0.2]:5701 - 69284e57-ce61-405c-87d3-1e9ea46b2bed this
]

Sep 29, 2020 6:35:37 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.132.0.2]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.132.0.2]:5701 is STARTED
```

The containers in node `10.128.0.3` are run with:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/mnt --rm --name member2   -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Dhazelcast.local.p
ublicAddress=10.128.0.3:5701 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.yml"   -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:4.0.1

########################################
# JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=10.128.0.3:5701 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.yml
# CLASSPATH=/opt/hazelcast/*:/opt/hazelcast/lib/*
# starting now....
########################################
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:54 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator
INFO: Loading configuration '/mnt/hazelcast.yml' from System property 'hazelcast.config'
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:54 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator
INFO: Using configuration file at /mnt/hazelcast.yml
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:55 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [10.128.0.3, 10.132.0.2]
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:55 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:55 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
WARNING: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:55 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Picked [172.17.0.2]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:55 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Using public address: [10.128.0.3]:5701
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:55 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Hazelcast 4.0.1 (20200409 - e086b9c) starting at [10.128.0.3]:5701
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:55 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:56 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Backpressure is disabled
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:56 AM com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Creating TcpIpJoiner
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:56 AM com.hazelcast.cp.CPSubsystem
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] CP Subsystem is not enabled. CP data structures will operate in UNSAFE mode! Please note that UNSAFE mode will not provide strong consistency guarantees.
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.128.0.3]:5701 is STARTING
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5703, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:36:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /172.17.0.2:56429 and /10.132.0.2:5701
Sep 29, 2020 6:37:05 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
        Member [10.132.0.2]:5701 - 69284e57-ce61-405c-87d3-1e9ea46b2bed
        Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f242-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e this
]

Sep 29, 2020 6:37:06 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.128.0.3]:5701 is STARTED
Sep 29, 2020 6:37:08 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.132.0.2:5702. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:37:08 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5702. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:37:08 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.132.0.2:5703. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
```

So far everything is ok, but when I start member 3:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/mnt --rm --name member3   -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Dhazelcast.local.p
ublicAddress=10.128.0.3:5702 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.yml"   -p 5702:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:4.0.1

########################################
# JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -XX:M
axRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.ni
o.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.manageme
nt.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=10.128.0.3:5702 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.yml
# CLASSPATH=/opt/hazelcast/*:/opt/hazelcast/lib/*
# starting now....
########################################
+ exec java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properti
es -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-
UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.bas
e/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.
management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=10.128.0.3:5702 -Dhazelcast.config=/mnt/hazelcast.y
ml com.hazelcast.core.server.HazelcastMemberStarter
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator
INFO: Loading configuration '/mnt/hazelcast.yml' from System property 'hazelcast.config'
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator
INFO: Using configuration file at /mnt/hazelcast.yml
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [10.12
8.0.3, 10.132.0.2]
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
WARNING: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback address
es.
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Picked [172.17.0.3]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind
 any local is true
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.1] Using public address: [10.128.0.3]:5702
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Hazelcast 4.0.1 (20200409 - e086b9c) starting at [10.128.0.3]:5702
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:26 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:27 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Backpressure is disabled
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:27 AM com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Creating TcpIpJoiner
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:27 AM com.hazelcast.cp.CPSubsystem
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] CP Subsystem is not enabled. CP data structures will operate in UNSAFE mod
e! Please note that UNSAFE mode will not provide strong consistency guarantees.
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:27 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority 
tasks)
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:27 AM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to t
he JVM arguments.
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:27 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] [10.128.0.3]:5702 is STARTING
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:28 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5703, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:28 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:28 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:28 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.132.0.2:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:28 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /172.17.0.3:52951 and /10.132.0.2:
5701
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:35 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] 
Members {size:3, ver:3} [
        Member [10.132.0.2]:5701 - 69284e57-ce61-405c-87d3-1e9ea46b2bed
        Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f242-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
        Member [10.128.0.3]:5702 - 0dd31ea2-db2e-4e43-941a-98592e222817 this
]
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:38 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.132.0.2:5703. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:38 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:38 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.132.0.2:5702. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:38 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:48 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:48 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:38:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:08 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:18 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:18 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionErrorHandler
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Removing connection to endpoint [10.128.0.3]:5701 Cause => java.net.Socket
TimeoutException {null}, Error-Count: 5
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:18 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MembershipManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f242-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e is suspect
ed to be dead for reason: No connection
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:18 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:27 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] This node does not have a connection to Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f24
2-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:28 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:28 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionErrorHandler
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Removing connection to endpoint [10.128.0.3]:5701 Cause => java.net.Socket
TimeoutException {null}, Error-Count: 6
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:32 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] This node does not have a connection to Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f24
2-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:37 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] This node does not have a connection to Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f24
2-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:38 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:42 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] This node does not have a connection to Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f24
2-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:47 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] This node does not have a connection to Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f24
2-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:48 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:48 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionErrorHandler
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Removing connection to endpoint [10.128.0.3]:5701 Cause => java.net.Socket
TimeoutException {null}, Error-Count: 7
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:48 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Connecting to /10.128.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:52 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] This node does not have a connection to Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f24
2-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:57 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] This node does not have a connection to Member [10.128.0.3]:5701 - aa22f24
2-cc82-44ff-9dc1-06678d14420e
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Could not connect to: /10.128.0.3:5701. Reason: SocketTimeoutException[null]
Sep 29, 2020 6:39:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionErrorHandler
WARNING: [10.128.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.1] Removing connection to endpoint [10.128.0.3]:5701 Cause => java.net.Socket
TimeoutException {null}, Error-Count: 8
```

It looks like there is a communication problem between the members on the same node
In another test the member3 replaced in the cluster the member2 and it marked the connection attemps from node2 as suspicious

The VM are made fresh on GCP and are on the same network, I used this image:

`Google, Container-Optimized OS, 85-13310.1041.9 stable, Kernel: ChromiumOS-5.4.49 Kubernetes: 1.18.9 Docker: 19.03.9 Family: cos-stable, supports Shielded VM features, supports Confidential VM features on N2D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by member3 that thinks to be on the port 5701 instead of the 5702.
The solution is to specify in the configuration the port where the member will listen on the docker host

The configuration for the member3 is

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    port:
      port: 5702
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - 10.132.0.2:5701
          - 10.128.0.3:5701
          - 10.128.0.3:5702
```

In this way the cluster works and every member can communicate with others.

Comment: I think this answer solves the issue, however I think this can be considered a bug. I've created a GH Issue here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker/issues/169

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario should work and I guess it will be some environmental issue. Could you try the following 2 things?

#### Explicitly set port also on member1

Use `:5701` also in member1 configuration - both `member-list` (`hazelcast.yml`) and `hazelcast.local.publicAddress` property (command-line).

This step probably changes nothing for your problem, but it should at least avoid non-related warnings in the logs.

#### Try if member2 is reachable from member3

After you start your nodes, execute an interactive shell in `member3` and try to send protocol challenge (`HZC`) to `member2`'s socket address. If you see the protocol response (`HZC`) in the terminal, then the communication between containers works properly. If you don't see the response, then check your Docker and firewall configuration to see what can cause the issue.

```sh
docker exec -it member3 /bin/bash

# Following command runs in container.
# The first HZC line is the one you type (followed by Enter).
# The second is the reply from member2.

bash-5.0# nc 10.128.0.3 5701
HZC
HZC
```

If you see the correct protocol response in the terminal we will need to investigate the Hazelcast behavior more. I was not able to reproduce the problem in my environment.

Comment: I have no response to the challenge: `$ docker exec -it member3 /bin/bash
bash-5.0  # nc 10.128.0.3 5701`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take this a little further, Hazelcast supports the lifecycle calls into containers and from orchestration managers (i.e. K8s and OpenShift), for this you use the hazelcast network discovery module for that particular platform. This free's you from hard-coding addresses and ports and allows those assignments to be done dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Thanks but which discovery can be used in this scenario? I'm open to add containers or simple to configure services to avoid to write IP and ports